# Is there an rpm for Tomcat 7 on RedHat Enterprise 6?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, redhat, rpm, rhel6

I am looking to install Tomcat 7 on RHEL6 using an RPM package, but it seems difficult to locate an RPM which installs components to their standard RedHat locations.

Is there a simple community RPM for this?

Comment: Why do you need to install Tomcat from RPM? Tomcat installation from tar.gz/zip is preety straightforward... (even when you need to create dedicated OS user etc.)

Comment: It's just how things seem to be done in the environment I recently started working in.

I personally have no issues with a tarball.

Comment: Note that tarball distributions tend to lack some pretty important features.  For example, they tend to not have managed logging, which typically means that it's a matter of time (sometimes that time is very long) before you potentially fill up your partition.  Other important items include the proper elevation of permissions just until you bind a low number port and then dropping down to "system user" permissions.  And of course, it is nice to not have to manually integrate with your service framework, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you *could* do is repackage the tomcat files into your own rpm.  These links show where others have attempted that sort of thing:

- [How to package a zip file into rpm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894553/how-to-package-a-zip-file-into-rpm-package)
- [Create Binary RPM from ZIP-File](http://lists.rpm.org/pipermail/rpm-list/2009-March/000220.html)

Interesting, both made the same error.  To clarify, here is a fixed version of the former's example:

```
Summary: tar to rpm sample script
Name: sample
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: X11
Source: sample.tar.gz

%global my_target /usr/local/sample

%description
tar to rpm sample script

%prep

%setup -q -n %{name}

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{my_target}
cp -p -r . $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{my_target}/

%build

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%{my_target}
```

To accomplish this, you would need [`rpmbuild`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/rpmbuild.8.html) installed, and create a simple spec-file that (in its `%setup` section) unpacks your tar-file, and then copies that to the target under `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`.  The `%build` section is empty because `%setup` does all of the work.

Then (with `sample.tar.gz` in `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES`) you could do

```
rpmbuild -ba sample.spec
```

and get a usable rpm under `~/rpmbuild/RPMS`.  (Use `rpm -qlp` on the
package to check it before installing).

Comment: We ended up doing something very similar to this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The [JPackage](http://jpackage.org/) project has been focused on providing rpms for Java-related applications and libraries.

Unfortunately, this project seems to be more or less abandoned now, but can at least serve as an example implementation.